# Replace all values in a matrix <0.1 with 0

Tags: r, replace

I have a matrix (2601 by 58) of particulate matter concentration estimates from an air quality model.  Because real-life air quality monitors cannot measure below 0.1 ug/L, I need to replace all values in my matrix that are `<0.1` with a zero/NA/null value.

Someone suggested `ifelse(test, true, false)` with a logical statement, but when I try this it deletes everything.

Comment: The question about what to replace negative or zero values with is an interesting one. Because so many models are built on a log(y) basis, I often replace them with the midpoint between the lower limit of normal and zero. (Probably a secondary question best posed on stats.exchange.)

Comment: @Dwin, +1 to that comment. I'd like to see that second question, and it's answers on crossvalidated.com

Comment: that's an interesting comment- i see what you're saying... For context, I'm using these values in a regression with emergency department data (population epidemiology study). The explanation I was given for why to replace the <0.1 with 0 was that we don't want to overestimate the effect... something to do with "zero inflated"?

Comment: @mEvans: Interesting. "zero-inflated" is a term for models that deal with too many zeroes, so you may well be creating a data situation that requires analyses that properly deal with "zero-inflated data"

Comment: Any data.frame solutions to this question?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`ifelse` should work:

```
mat <- matrix(runif(100),ncol=5)
mat <- ifelse(mat<0.1,NA,mat)
```

But I would choose Harlan's answer over mine.

```
mat[mat < 0.1] <- NA
```

Comment: The thing with ifelse is it seems to turn my matrix into a vector... would I be able to re-shape it into a matrix somehow?

Comment: @mEvans it doesn't for me!  if I paste my code i get the matrix back out... but yes you can always convert a `vector` to a `matrix` using `matrix(mat)`.  Take a look at all the optional arguments to `matrix` too. But, like I said in my answer, I think Harlan's answer is best by a long shot.

Answer (score 88):

```
X[X < .1] <- 0
```

(or NA, although 0 sounds more appropriate in this case.)

Matrices are just vectors with dimensions, so you can treat them like a vector when you assign to them. In this case, you're creating a boolean vector over X that indicates the small values, and it assigns the right-hand-side to each element that's TRUE.

Comment: Can you do this to only certain columns?  It's replacing other values in other columns (like dates and times, etc) when I run it on the whole matrix.

Comment: For a subset of cols, you could use: `X[, c(1,3,5)] <- apply(X[, c(1,3,5)], 2, function(x) ifelse(x < 0.1, 0, x))` (for columns 1, 3 and 5).

Comment: @mEvans: if you have different types of data in different columns, that means you probably have a data frame, not a matrix. These are different critters in R, although many operations will work with both. You should check what your dataset is before doing anything else, as that will probably save you a lot of pain later.

Comment: @jbaums that works nicely for matrices, but not vectors. For example, the case X[,1] (using only 1 column) fails because dim(X[,1]) = NULL. What bothers me is that the function description says it works with vectors (which have length, but no dimension) and matrices (has length and dimension).

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé - you could add `drop=FALSE` to ensure it'll work with a single column.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find that 'ifelse' is not a vector operation (its actually performing as a loop), and so it is orders of magnitudes slower than the vector equivalent. R favors vector operations, which is why apply, mapply, sapply are lightning fast for certain calculations.

Small Datasets, not a problem, but if you have an array of length 100k or more, you can go and cook a roast dinner before it finishes under any method involving a loop.

The below code should work.

For vector

```
minvalue <- 0
X[X < minvalue] <- minvalue
```

For Dataframe or Matrix.

```
minvalue <- 0
n <- 10 #change to whatever.
columns <- c(1:n)
X[X[,columns] < minvalue,columns] <- minvalue
```

Another fast method, via pmax and pmin functions, this caps entries between 0 and 1 and you can put a matrix or dataframe as the first argument no problems.

```
ulbound <- function(v,MAX=1,MIN=0) pmin(MAX,pmax(MIN,v))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide an (in my opinion) interesting alternative:

If you need to clamp the values so they are never smaller than a value, you could use `pmax`:

```
set.seed(42)
m <- matrix(rnorm(100),10)

m <- pmax(m, 0) # clamp negative values to 0
```

...This doesn't quite work in your case though since you want values < 0.1 to become 0.

Answer (score 1):

Further equivalent methods:

let:

```
M=matrix(rnorm(10*10), 10, 10)
```

Brute force (educative)

```
for (i in 1:nrow(M)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(M)) if (M[i,j]<0.1 & !is.na(M[i,j]) ) M[i,j]=NA
    }
```

If there are missing values (NA) in M, omitting `!is.na` will give errors.

Another way: using `recode` in package `car`:

```
library(car)
recode(M, "lo:0.099999=NA")
```

Can't specify a strict inequality here, so that's why there's a bunch of 9. Put more nines and it turns into 0.1. `lo` is a convenience of recode, which gives the minimum value (removing NAs).

Answer (score 1):

A data.frame solution:

```
if(!require(plyr)){
    install.packages("plyr")}

rm.neg<-colwise(function(x){
  return(ifelse(x < 0.1, 0, x))})

rm.neg(data.frame(mat))
```

PS: the code for rm.neg can be extracted and simplified so as not to need a call to plyr, which is used to create the colwise function.