# R: Quickest way to create dataframe with an alternative to IFELSE

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, random, dataframe

I have a similar question this the one on this thread:
[Using R, replace all values in a matrix <0.1 with 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439619/using-r-replace-all-values-in-a-matrix-0-1-with-0)

But in my case I have hypothetically larger dataset and variable thresholds. 
I need to create a dataframe with each value retrieved from a condition using the values on the first columns of the same dataframe. These values are different for each line.

Here is an example of the dataframe:

```
SNP        A1  A2   MAF     
rs3094315  G   A   0.172  
rs7419119  G   T   0.240  
rs13302957 G   A   0.081  
rs6696609  T   C   0.393
```

Here is a sample of my code:

```
seqIndividuals = seq(1:201)
for(i in seqIndividuals) {
  alFrequ[paste("IND",i,"a",sep="")] = ifelse(runif(length(alFrequ$SNP),0.00,1.00) < alFrequ$MAF, alFrequ$A1, alFrequ$A2)
  alFrequ[paste("IND",i,"b",sep="")] = ifelse(runif(length(alFrequ$SNP),0.00,1.00) < alFrequ$MAF, alFrequ$A1, alFrequ$A2)
}
```

I am creating two new columns for each individual "i" in "seqIndividuals" by retrieving either values from column "A1" if a random value if lower than column "MAF", or "A2" if higher. The code is working great, but as a dataset grows in rows and columns (individuals) the time also grows significantly.

Is there a way to avoid using IFELSE for this situation, as I understand it works as a loop? I tried generating a matrix of random values and then replacing them, but it takes the same time or even longer.

```
mtxAlFrequ = matrix(runif(length(alFrequ$SNP)*(201)),nrow=length(alFrequ$SNP),ncol=201)
mtxAlFrequ[mtxAlFrequ < alFrequ$MAF] = alFrequ$A1
```

Thanks!

Comment: The two `ifelse` statements seems to be doing the same thing except for the `runif` part.  If that is the case, you can use `replicate(2, runif(...`

Comment: Hi @akrun. They are doing the same, just creating a column with a different name, but I can change the names afterwards. Will that increase the speed significantly? Thanks

Comment: Try `lst <- do.call(c, lapply(seqIndividuals, function(i) replicate(2, alFrequ[2:3][cbind(1:nrow(alFrequ), (runif(nrow(alFrequ), 0, 1) >= alFrequ$MAF)+1)], simplify=FALSE)));
nm1 <- paste0("IND", rep(letters[1:2], length(seqIndividuals)), rep(seqIndividuals, each = 2));
alFrequ[nm1] <- lst`

Comment: Please try the code above and check whether it increased the speed

Comment: Akrun, it is indeed faster, but not much: 510sec vs 535sec with 340.000 rows. I wouldn't expect using a lot more than 340K rows, so the change is not very significant.

Comment: I posted a solution with `data.table`.

Comment: According to the timings with data.table, it is around 10 secs for 340K rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- paste0("IND", rep(letters[1:2], length(seqIndividuals)), 
                    rep(seqIndividuals, each = 2))
setDT(alFrequ)
for(j in seq_along(nm1)) {
      alFrequ[, nm1[j] := A2
             ][runif(.N, 0, 1) < MAF , nm1[j] := A1][]
}
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(24)
alFrequ <- data.frame(SNP= paste0('rs', sample(600000, 340000, replace=FALSE)),
                   A1 = sample(c("G", "T", "A", "C"), 340000, replace=TRUE),
                   A2 = sample(c("G", "T", "A", "C"), 340000, replace=TRUE),
                   MAF = runif(340000, 0, 1), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
nm1 <- paste0("IND", rep(letters[1:2], length(seqIndividuals)), 
                          rep(seqIndividuals, each = 2))

system.time({
    setDT(alFrequ)
     for(j in seq_along(nm1)){
     alFrequ[, nm1[j] := A2][runif(.N, 0, 1) < MAF , nm1[j] := A1][]
   }
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  10.72    1.05   11.76
```

and using the OP's code on the original dataset

```
system.time({
 for(i in seqIndividuals) {
   alFrequ[paste("IND",i,"a",sep="")] = ifelse(runif(length(alFrequ$SNP),0.00,1.00) < 
          alFrequ$MAF, alFrequ$A1, alFrequ$A2)
   alFrequ[paste("IND",i,"b",sep="")] = ifelse(runif(length(alFrequ$SNP),0.00,1.00) < 
             alFrequ$MAF, alFrequ$A1, alFrequ$A2)
 }
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   72.16    6.82   79.33
```

Comment: 490 seconds, the fastest so far. Some improvement, but if you come across another idea let me know :) Might just be impossible though.

Comment: @DanielFernandes  For me, it is 10 seconds on the 340,000 rows you mentioned using data.table 1.10.0 and R 3.3.2

Comment: Ok, I see I have data.table 1.9.6. Let me try updating it. As a note, I am running this on a laptop right now (i7, 8GB RAM).

Comment: @DanielFernandes In the mean time, I will also run your code and check the timings.  I have a 16 GB RAM i5

Comment: I just ran your whole code, including the randomly generated <alFrequ> and it did take only 9 secs...

Comment: I found my problem. My `MAF` column was of type `character`. I changed it to `double` as in your randomized dataframe and now it is on-time with it. Thanks!

Comment: I see data.table is where to go on large datasets. Thanks for that. Also, do you know how to assign values from a different data.frame/data.table after the `:=`?

Comment: @DanielFernandes  If it needs a join, then do it after the join.  I didn't completely understand your question.  Please post it as a new question.