# Adding column to existing data table, using formula from one column and operand data from other column

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I'm a beginner in R, I have the following data, where table is like this:

```
dt
    fct X Y Z   fct1 Q
 1:   a 2 1 a:a    a a:a:2
 2:   b 4 2 b:b    b b:b:4
 3:   c 3 1 c:c    c c:c:3
 4:   d 2 2 d:d    d d:d:2
 5:   c 5 1 c:c    c c:c:5
 6:   d 4 2 d:d    d d:d:4
 7:   a 7 1 a:a    a a:a:7
 8:   b 2 2 b:b    b b:b:2
 9:   c 9 1 c:c    c c:c:9
10:   a 1 2 a:a    a a:a:1
11:   b 4 1 b:b    b b:b:4
12:   c 2 2 c:c    c c:c:2
13:   b 5 1 b:b    b b:b:5
14:   c 4 2 c:c    c c:c:4
15:   d 2 1 d:d    d d:d:2`
```

and, have a List like this:

```
flist
$a
[1] "X + Y"
$b
[1] "X - Y"
$c
[1] "X * Y"
$d
[1] "paste0(Z,':',fct)"
```

Since `flist` has an entry for `a`, whenever an entry `a` in `fct` column is seen, then the corresponding formula from the list needs to be executed, using the values of `Y` and `Z` column, and applied to Column `XY`.

I tried solution like this:

`within(dt2, XY <-  eval(parse(text=flist['a'])))`, which works with the clearly seen constraint, which is, it can only be applied with the formula for `a`.

However, this: `within(dt2, XY <-  eval(parse(text=flist[fct])))` doesn't work.
Even this: `within(dt2, XY <-  eval(parse(text=eval(parse(text=flist[fct]))))))` doesn't work.

Use case is that, looking into `fct` Column, its variable should be used to look up the formula in `flist`, and then applied with the Data in `X` and `Y` and applied to `XY`.

I kindly look forward for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `data.table` methods by specifying the logical condition in 'i' (assuming that 'fct' is `character` class and assign (`:=`) the evaluated string from the `list` element (`flist$a`) to create the new column 'XY'

```
dt[fct == names(flist), XY := eval(parse(text=flist$a))]
dt
#    fct X Y   Z fct1     Q XY
# 1:   a 2 1 a:a    a a:a:2  3
# 2:   b 4 2 b:b    b b:b:4 NA
# 3:   c 3 1 c:c    c c:c:3 NA
# 4:   d 2 2 d:d    d d:d:2 NA
# 5:   c 5 1 c:c    c c:c:5 NA
# 6:   d 4 2 d:d    d d:d:4 NA
# 7:   a 7 1 a:a    a a:a:7  8
# 8:   b 2 2 b:b    b b:b:2 NA
# 9:   c 9 1 c:c    c c:c:9 NA
#10:   a 1 2 a:a    a a:a:1  3
#11:   b 4 1 b:b    b b:b:4 NA
#12:   c 2 2 c:c    c c:c:2 NA
#13:   b 5 1 b:b    b b:b:5 NA
#14:   c 4 2 c:c    c c:c:4 NA
#15:   d 2 1 d:d    d d:d:2 NA
```

#### Update

If there are multiple elements in 'flist'

```
for(j in seq_along(flist)){
  dt[fct == names(flist)[j], XY := eval(parse(text= flist[[j]]))][]
}

dt
#    fct X Y   Z fct1     Q XY
# 1:   a 2 1 a:a    a a:a:2  3
# 2:   b 4 2 b:b    b b:b:4  2
# 3:   c 3 1 c:c    c c:c:3  3
# 4:   d 2 2 d:d    d d:d:2 NA
# 5:   c 5 1 c:c    c c:c:5  5
# 6:   d 4 2 d:d    d d:d:4 NA
# 7:   a 7 1 a:a    a a:a:7  8
# 8:   b 2 2 b:b    b b:b:2  0
# 9:   c 9 1 c:c    c c:c:9  9
#10:   a 1 2 a:a    a a:a:1  3
#11:   b 4 1 b:b    b b:b:4  3
#12:   c 2 2 c:c    c c:c:2  4
#13:   b 5 1 b:b    b b:b:5  4
#14:   c 4 2 c:c    c c:c:4  8
#15:   d 2 1 d:d    d d:d:2 NA
```

#### data

```
flist <- list(a= "X + Y")
#updated flist
flist <- list(a = "X + Y", b = "X - Y", c = "X * Y")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, What if we have more than one index in `flist`? `flist$a` can't be applied, isn't it?

Comment: @abdulrahmank  If your point of interest is in the 'a' element then specify it in the `i`, i.e. `dt[fct == 'a', XY := eval(parse(text=flist$a))]`

Comment: Actually, I have index for b, c and d as well. Hence need to apply all the formula correspondingly. @akrun

Comment: thank you for the answer, it works for me. I have one question, of whether to use for loop, or nested ifelse statement and create a string and then eval it

Comment: @abdulrahmank  I would say to use a `for` loop as the `ifelse` can be slow.  Here, we are assigning and it is very fast as it is done in place.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, @akrun

Comment: @abdulrahmank  You can also check the benchmarks [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41313507/r-quickest-way-to-create-dataframe-with-an-alternative-to-ifelse/41313931#41313931) which is much faster than `ifelse`