# R: Efficiently fill data.table column retrieving variable values from different DT

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Earlier today I asked this [R: Quickest way to create dataframe with an alternative to IFELSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41313507/r-quickest-way-to-create-dataframe-with-an-alternative-to-ifelse#).

The solution given by @akrun of using `data.table` worked miracles, but when trying to implement the same approach to a slightly more intricate situation it became actually 4 times slower than using a `for` loop over two `data.frame` with 4 embedded `ifelse` statements.

Given a `data.frame` or `data.table` named `alFrequ`:

```
SNP        A1  A2   MAF   IND1a  IND1b  IND2a  IND2b  IND3a  IND3b   etc..
rs3094315  G   A   0.172    A      A      A      G      A      A      ..
rs7419119  G   T   0.240    G      T      T      G      G      G      ..
rs13302957 G   A   0.081    A      A      A      A      A      A      ..
rs6696609  T   C   0.393    T      C      C      C      T      T      ..
```

From each group of 6 columns I want to create a new `data.frame` with pairs of columns (here labelled with the pair of `IND` and "I" and "II") where each column is based on two columns from the previous `data.frame`.

For example, for the first pair, I want two columns based on the pair `IND1-IND2` - the first one based on `IND1` only, and the second in `IND2` only. So it randomly chooses one of the values from `IND1a` and `IND1b` to assign to `1-2I`, then `IND2a` and `IND2b` for `IND1-2II`. For the second pair I want to repeat the first `IND` used,`IND1a` and `IND1b`, and finally the third `IND` , `IND3a` and `IND3b`.

```
SNP        A1  A2   MAF     1-2I    1-2II    1-3I    1-3II    etc..
rs3094315  G   A   0.172      A        A       A       A        ..
rs7419119  G   T   0.240      T        G       T       G        ..
rs13302957 G   A   0.081      A        A       A       A        ..
rs6696609  T   C   0.393      T        C       C       T        ..
```

I have used the following code before and it works fine, but gets somewhat slow on large datasets.

```
numPairs = 100
numInds = (numPairs *2)+1  ##Correction for permutations
seqInds = seq(1:numInds)
nm1 = colnames(alFrequ)

halfS=alFrequ[1:5]
iter=1
for(i in seqInds){
  nextInd=iter+1
  nextNextInd=nextInd+1
  if(nextInd <= numInds) {
    halfS[paste(iter,"-",nextInd,"I",sep="")] = ifelse(runif(length(alFrequ$SNP),0.00,1.00) < 0.5, c(alFrequ[paste("IND",iter,"a",sep="")])[[1]], c(alFrequ[paste("IND",iter,"b",sep="")])[[1]])
    halfS[paste(iter,"-",nextInd,"II",sep="")] = ifelse(runif(length(alFrequ$SNP),0.00,1.00) < 0.5, c(alFrequ[paste("IND",nextInd,"a",sep="")])[[1]], c(alFrequ[paste("IND",nextInd,"b",sep="")])[[1]])
    halfS[paste(iter,"-",nextNextInd,"I",sep="")] = ifelse(runif(length(alFrequ$SNP),0.00,1.00) < 0.5, c(alFrequ[paste("IND",iter,"a",sep="")])[[1]], c(alFrequ[paste("IND",iter,"b",sep="")])[[1]])
    halfS[paste(iter,"-",nextNextInd,"II",sep="")] = ifelse(runif(length(alFrequ$SNP),0.00,1.00) < 0.5, c(alFrequ[paste("IND",nextNextInd,"a",sep="")])[[1]], c(alFrequ[paste("IND",nextNextInd,"b",sep="")])[[1]])
  }
  iter=iter+2
}
```

I then tried using the `data.table` approach suggested on my other thread, but it becomes even slower than the old code.

```
namesHS = paste0("HSIB", rep(seq(from=1,to=length(seqInds)-2,by=2),each=4),"-",rep(seq(from=2,to=length(seqInds),by=1),each=2),rep(c("I","II"),each=2,times=numPairs),"_",rep(letters[1:2], length(seqInds)-2))
halfS = data.frame(matrix(ncol = numPairs*4,nrow = length(alFrequ$SNP)))
colnames(halfS) = namesHS
system.time({
  setDT(alFrequ)
  setDT(halfS)
  for(j in seq(from=1,to=numPairs*4,by=4)){
    print(j)
    ind1AlA=j
    ind1AlB=j+1
    ind2AlA=j+2
    ind2AlB=j+3
    ind3AlA=j+4
    ind3AlB=j+5
    halfS[, namesHS[j] := alFrequ[,get(as.character(nm1[ind1AlA]))]][runif(.N, 0, 1) < 0.5, alFrequ[,get(as.character(nm1[ind1AlB]))]][]
    halfS[, namesHS[j+1] := alFrequ[,get(as.character(nm1[ind2AlA]))]][runif(.N, 0, 1) < 0.5, alFrequ[,get(as.character(nm1[ind2AlB]))]][]
    halfS[, namesHS[j+2] := alFrequ[,get(as.character(nm1[ind1AlA]))]][runif(.N, 0, 1) < 0.5, alFrequ[,get(as.character(nm1[ind1AlB]))]][]
    halfS[, namesHS[j+3] := alFrequ[,get(as.character(nm1[ind3AlA]))]][runif(.N, 0, 1) < 0.5, alFrequ[,get(as.character(nm1[ind3AlB]))]][]
  }
})
```

Can the `get` function be the cause?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you don't need the `get(as.character(..` wouldn't just `alFrequ[[nm1[ind1AlA]]]` works?

Comment: In that situation it actually writes in the new column the corresponding name of the column, for example, "IND1a". It does not go pick the column values themselves.

Comment: Correction @akrun, got it to work, had missed a parenthesis. Thanks once again!

Comment: But it does not randomize the values...Always writes the column retrieved on the first condition and ignores the condition inside the `runif`. If I add `namesHS[j] :=` to the `runif` part of the lines, then only a limited number of items to be replaced seem to be used, giving a warning for each line. `1: In `[.data.table`(halfS[, `:=`(namesHS[j], alFrequ[[nm1[ind1AlA]]])],  ... :
  Supplied 112966 items to be assigned to 56404 items of column '1-2I' (56562 unused)`

Comment: In the second part of the code, I didn't find you assiging it back to `namesHS[j] :=` i.e. `[runif(.N, 0, 1) < 0.5, namesHS[j] :=` Also create the 'alFreq[[nm[ind1AlB]]]` column in the dataset and assign it based on index