# How can I replace values in an R matrix matching on rowname, columnname and value

Tags: r

I have a really big matrix and I'd like to replace the values in it using a lookup table.

I have a table of values (which looks a bit like this):

```
Origin  Destination  Distance  Final
  1         1           1         A
  1         1           2         B
  1         1           3         E      
  1         2           2         F
  1         3           1         B
  1         3           2         C   
  2         1           1         B
  2         2           1         A
  2         3           3         C
  3         1           1         A
  3         1           2         D
  3         2           1         B
  3         3           2         A    
 ...
```

and I have a matrix, which looks something like this:

```
x   1   1   3   1   2    1  ...
1   1   3   2   1   2    1  
1   2   2   1   2   2    1
3   2   1   2   1   1    2
1   3   1   2   1   2    1
2   1   1   3   1   1    1
1   2   2   1   3   1    1

...
```

I'm trying to match my matrix rownames with the Origin column, the matrix Colnames with the Destination Column and the matrix values with the Distance Column and then replace that value with the Final Column.

The Matrix is 4000 by 4000.
The Table is 27 by 4

So when I'm done it should look like:

```
     x   1   1   3   1   2    1  ...
     1   A   E   C   A   F    A  
     1   B   B   B   B   F    A
     3   D   A   A   A   B    A
     1   E   A   C   A   F    A
     2   B   B   C   B   A    B
     1   B   B   B   E   A    A
    ...
```

I'm currently using a little loop, which looks like this;

```
for (i in 1:nrow(CategoryTable)){

      Origin <- CategoryTable[i,"O"]
      Dest <- CategoryTable[i,"D"]
      Distance <- CategoryTable[i,"Dist"]
      Final <- CategoryTable[i,"Final"]

      CategoryGrid[CategoryGrid == Distance][CategoryGrid[row.names(CategoryGrid) %in% Origin,colnames(CategoryGrid) %in% Dest]] <-CategoryTable[i,"Final"]   

      }
```

Based on this question ([Replace all values in a matrix <0.1 with 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439619/replace-all-values-in-a-matrix-0-1-with-0)) I can replace all the things matching a specific value or the things matching a column or row. But I can't match all at once.

The active ingredient of the current attempt is:

```
CategoryGrid[CategoryGrid == Distance][CategoryGrid[row.names(CategoryGrid) %in% Origin,colnames(CategoryGrid) %in% Dest]] <-CategoryTable[i,"Final"]
```

So I was trying to match the rows and columns and then pass that as a boolean vector to the value match, and then do the RHS assignation.

However, what I actually get is:

```
Error in CategoryGrid[row.names(CategoryGrid) %in% Origin, colnames(CategoryGrid) %in%  : 
  incorrect number of dimensions
```

How would you go about achieving this?

Comment: Can you provide the expected results?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the active ingredient with the following did the trick.

```
CategoryGrid[row.names(CategoryGrid) == Origin , colnames(CategoryGrid) == Dest] <- apply(CategoryGrid[row.names(CategoryGrid) == Origin , colnames(CategoryGrid) == Dest], MARGIN=c(1,2),function(x) ifelse(x == Distance, Final, x))
```

Specify the rules for the rows and columns and then do an apply and put the third variable in it's own function.

Comment: This works, but is very slow. I'd love a faster version if there is one.