# How to loop through entire dataframe/every cell in R?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, cell, operation

I need to do a for loop and a true or false operation for each cell value in the table, if operation returns true, then the function is going to replace the value with 0. But the R throws me errors everytime i try to run the code

```
for (i in xxxxx(a number){
   for (j in xxx(a number){
     if (y[i,j] == 0 & y[i,j] < mean(y) - ppp / sd(y)){
       y[i,j] <- NA
     }
   }
}
```

> Error in [.data.table(y, i, j) :    j (the 2nd argument inside
>   [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'j' is not found. Perhaps
>   you intended DT[, ..j]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate
>   and explained in FAQ 1.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace all values in a matrix <0.1 with 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439619/replace-all-values-in-a-matrix-0-1-with-0)

Comment: What are the `xxxxx` and the `xxx` functions?  Further, R won't accept `a number` as an input so this is probably mot the code that you run. It is easier to answer if your example is reproducible and you show the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how you're supposed to do `mean(y)` and `sd(y)`, as `y` seems to be a data table based on your code.

Your `mean(y)` would have thrown an error, but your `y[i,j]` errored first, most likely it's because your `i` or `j` doesn't make sense.

If your `y` is all numbers, you can use matrix instead of `data.table`. Vectorizing the solution is always faster in R.

```
y <- as.matrix(y);

y[some condition for y] <- NA
```

If vectorizing is not an option, the way you loop through cells is also slow. When you use `[i, j]`, it takes time for R to find the row. You can take a look at [my test](https://github.com/chnynf/r-experiments/blob/master/speed-tests.R).