# How to filter or subset data in R per row

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, row, subset

I am relatively new to R and still figuring out how to filter data from a dataframe. I have a dataframe consisting of 406 rows and 48 columns, with some missing data:

```
set.seed(123)
mydata <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(406*48), nrow = 406, ncol = 48))
diag(mydata) <- NA
mydata[10:20,25:40] <- NA
```

What I now want to do is go through each row and select all entries that are <= zero. I would like to store these entries in a new variable.
My code, which is not working, looks as following:

```
newdata <- c()
#go through each row
for (j in 1:nrow(mydata)){
#within each row look at all the entries, store all entries that are <= 0 in a new variable, rowwise
  for (i in 1:ncol(mydata)){
    newdata[] <- mydata[j,i][mydata[j,i]<= 0]
}
}
```

As an end result for `newdata` I would like to have a variable with 406 rows where in each row I have all the entries of the respective row of `mydata` that are <= zero.  As I have several `NA`, it is okay for each row in `newdata` to have a different amount of entries.

Can anybody help?

Comment: So in places where you're dropping the data (i.e. values > 0), what do you intend to have? `NA`?

Comment: I just want to drop those values.

Comment: But then what would the layout of the matrix look like? You might have one row keep 10 values and one keep 8—what would be in those remaining 2 spaces? The dimensions need to be consistent, unless there's some other structure you're thinking of besides a matrix or data frame

Comment: Then in cases of values>0, I would also like to to have ```NA```.

Comment: @Friederike, in my answer below, I provide you two ways to get rid of positive values and replace it by `NA`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace all values in a matrix <0.1 with 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439619/replace-all-values-in-a-matrix-0-1-with-0)

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to simply replace postive values with `NA`, this can be
done very simply taking advantage of R's vectorization.

First let me make a smaller example dataset so we can see everything:

```
set.seed(1)
nrow <- 6
ncol <- 4
mydata <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(nrow * ncol), nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol))
diag(mydata) <- NA
mydata[4:5, 1:2] <- NA
mydata

##           X1        X2          X3          X4
## 1         NA 0.4874291 -0.62124058  0.82122120
## 2  0.1836433        NA -2.21469989  0.59390132
## 3 -0.8356286 0.5757814          NA  0.91897737
## 4         NA        NA -0.04493361          NA
## 5         NA        NA -0.01619026  0.07456498
## 6 -0.8204684 0.3898432  0.94383621 -1.98935170
```

This will work equally well on a larger dataset (in fact by avoiding
`apply` or a loop this approach will work even better).

Now it's as simple as making a boolean of what we want to set to `NA`
(in this case `mydata > 0`) and just doing it!

```
mydata[mydata > 0] <- NA
mydata

##           X1 X2          X3        X4
## 1         NA NA -0.62124058        NA
## 2         NA NA -2.21469989        NA
## 3 -0.8356286 NA          NA        NA
## 4         NA NA -0.04493361        NA
## 5         NA NA -0.01619026        NA
## 6 -0.8204684 NA          NA -1.989352
```

But from the OP it seems more like what you want is a **list** where
each element can have a different length (note: with a `data.frame` each
row *must* have the same number of entries; however a list allows each
element to have an arbitrary number of entries).

To make such a list you could, for example, try this:

```
mylist <- lapply(1:nrow(mydata), function(i) {
    x <- mydata[i, ]
    x[x <= 0 & !is.na(x)]
})
mylist

## [[1]]
## [1] -0.6212406
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] -2.2147
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] -0.8356286
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] -0.04493361
## 
## [[5]]
## [1] -0.01619026
## 
## [[6]]
## [1] -0.8204684 -1.9893517
```

Again, we have to use a list because not all elements are guaranteed to have the same length.

Comment: Nice ! I feel so stupid to not have think about `mydata[mydata > 0] <- NA` ;) That's definitely the easiest way to do.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION (ONE LINE)**

Alternatively (and based on your comments), you can do replace positive values by NA in one line using:

```r
mydata = apply(mydata,2,function(x){x = ifelse(x <= 0,x,NA)})
```

Here is the output of the first line of `mydata` before:

```r
> as.numeric(mydata[1,])
 [1]          NA -0.34975424 -0.07767320 -1.16193756 -0.33768064 -1.09321744  0.66392711  0.27303842 -2.23650827
[10] -0.42412913  1.44870575  0.03134468  0.19868021  0.17935206  1.51321052 -0.33100059  0.26331289 -0.20527804
[19] -0.22355074 -0.96041834 -0.82061841  0.67362771 -1.11751900 -0.58768884 -1.14399798  0.11782292 -1.51231253
[28] -1.93607886 -0.33478355  0.70214667  0.51443110 -1.04816477 -1.20696026 -0.97035477 -0.40159316  0.80351157
[37]  1.07208956  0.08778464  0.40148417  1.27912058 -0.90539292 -2.57307640 -0.38050016 -0.51386913  0.39852024
[46]  0.68074424 -0.04131547 -1.58519483
```

and after:

```r
> as.numeric(mydata[1,])
 [1]          NA -0.34975424 -0.07767320 -1.16193756 -0.33768064 -1.09321744          NA          NA -2.23650827
[10] -0.42412913          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA -0.33100059          NA -0.20527804
[19] -0.22355074 -0.96041834 -0.82061841          NA -1.11751900 -0.58768884 -1.14399798          NA -1.51231253
[28] -1.93607886 -0.33478355          NA          NA -1.04816477 -1.20696026 -0.97035477 -0.40159316          NA
[37]          NA          NA          NA          NA -0.90539292 -2.57307640 -0.38050016 -0.51386913          NA
[46]          NA -0.04131547 -1.58519483
```

**PREVIOUS SOLUTION**

Here is another solution, probably not the best one but it should looks ok.
With your dataframe as you described:

```r
set.seed(123)
mydata <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(406*48), nrow = 406, ncol = 48))
diag(mydata) <- NA
mydata[10:20,25:40] <- NA
```

We will basically create  a list to store all negative values of each row

```r
list_data = vector("list",nrow(mydata))
for(i in 1:nrow(mydata))
{
  list_data[[i]] = mydata[i,which(mydata[i,]<=0)]
}
```

Then, in order to transform the list into a dataframe, we fill up each missing values by NA values in order to have the exact same number of values per row

```r
maxlength = max(sapply(list_data,length))
List_Data = lapply(list_data, function(x){c(x,rep(NA,maxlength-length(x)))})
List_Data = do.call(rbind,List_Data)
List_Data = data.frame(List_Data)
```

And here the output for the first columns:

```r
> head(List_Data)
          X1         X2          X3          X4         X5         X6         X7          X8         X9
1         NA -0.3497542 -0.07767320 -1.16193756 -0.3376806 -1.0932174 -2.2365083 -0.42412913 -0.3310006
2 -0.2301775         NA -1.58908969 -0.03795763 -0.4079667 -0.2509906 -0.5778989 -0.14031375 -1.5660913
3 -0.5388092         NA -1.16618981 -0.22729115 -0.5017032 -1.0556810 -1.0237632 -0.89231744 -2.0031559
4         NA -1.0387278 -0.07765504 -0.15323396 -0.8953830 -1.3724905 -0.5035273 -0.05266103 -1.0722186
5 -0.1941524 -2.1645471          NA -0.90793470 -0.7849893 -0.8245955 -0.3935175 -0.18426891 -0.0757480
6 -0.6375688         NA -0.13461283 -1.03171727 -1.1625653 -0.7045958 -0.5746850 -0.19752782 -0.3510071
```

As, I said, there is probably fastest and more elegant way to achieve the same result but this solution works.